# Отладка с мобильного телефона локального сайта

Tags: ssh

Всем привет.
В далеком 2013 году я делал отладку сайта с мобильного телефона через сервер.
Примерная архитектура на картинке ниже:
[image: Архитектура]

Как видно из картинки я через интернет подключался к серверу.
Между сервером и моим локальным компьютером был реверсивный туннель.

В общую архитектуру я помню, но какими инструментами это делал не помню.

Что-то мне подсказывает что это было сделано через ssh+nginx. Но как именно не помню.

Собственно вопрос мануале как повторить это.

Ngrok не предлагать. Они просят карту, котороу потом нельзя удалить, только заменить на другую. Да и стоит 60 баксов за год, а мне отладка нужна на один вечер.

Comment: Запихиваете комп и телефон в общую локальную сеть да подключаетесь к компу по айпишнику, чё мудрить-то) У ваших телефонов ведь есть вайфай, я надеюсь?

Comment: @andreymal, на локалке виртуальная машина с убунтой и там вебвервер. 

Настроить маршрутизатор нет возможности. 

А настроить мост на локальной машине у меня недостаточно прямые руки. 
На винде получалось, но сейчас мак и я тут вообще не ориентируюсь в настройках сетей.